# Datatable - Functionality not working for Copy, CSV, PDF and Xls buttons but working for Print button

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I am able to display Copy, CSV, PDF and Xls and Print button just above the Database. Functionality is not working for Print button but not for Copy, CSV, PDF and Xls buttons.
Data is properly displaying inside the datatable.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    data: { stateid: $("#stateid").val() },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {

        if(data['aaData'].length > 0) {

            oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>layout/media/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "aButtons": ["copy","csv", "pdf","xls",
                                        {
                                            "sExtends": "print",
                                            "bShowAll": false,
                                            "sMessage":"<img src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>layout/media/images/asd.gif'/>"
                                        }
                                    ]
                },
                "data": data['aaData'],
                "order": [[0, "desc"]],
                "aoColumns": [
                    { mData: 'memberid' },
                    { mData: 'name' }
                ],
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayStart": 0,
                "iDisplayStart": 25,
                "bDestroy": true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Need to set below values

```
"sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
"oTableTools": {
                            "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                                "aButtons": ["copy","csv", "pdf","xls",
                                                {
                                                    "sExtends": "print",
                                                    "bShowAll": false,
                                                    "sMessage":"<img src='images/asd.gif'/>"
                                                }
                                            ]
                        }
```

Answer (score -1):

i had the same issue and the reason was that the swf file was not loaded from local server (wamp ) just use the cnd i'm not sure if this was only a security feature of chrome.

```
"sSwfPath" : "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it simply by inspecting chrome>console. I realized that tableTools was looking for the swf folder in a wrong place whose path did not exist in my html file.

I simply created that directory in that wrong place and copied the two swf files from media/swf to that directory and it worked.